# Error comes when i repeatedly press button 3-4 times/second. Animation problem

Tags: silverlight, animation, silverlight-4.0

I have created one custom control. This is the method which causes problem :-

```
private void Update(object newContent)
        {
            //lock (this)
            //{
                if (grid == null)
                    base.ApplyTemplate();

                ContentControl oldWrapper = this.currentWrappedControl;
                if (oldWrapper != null)
                {
                    VisualStateGroup layoutStatesGroup = findNameInWrapper(oldWrapper, "LayoutStates") as VisualStateGroup;

                    if (layoutStatesGroup == null)
                    {
                        this.grid.Children.Remove(oldWrapper);
                        setContent(oldWrapper, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        layoutStatesGroup.CurrentStateChanged += delegate(object sender, VisualStateChangedEventArgs args)
                        {

                            this.grid.Children.Remove(oldWrapper);
                            setContent(oldWrapper, null);
                        };
                        VisualStateManager.GoToState(oldWrapper, "BeforeUnloaded", true);
                    }
                }

                ContentControl newWrapper = new ContentControl();
                newWrapper.Style = TransitionStyle;
                newWrapper.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                newWrapper.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
                grid.Children.Add(newWrapper);
                newWrapper.ApplyTemplate();
                if (this.TransitionStyle != null)
                {
                    setContent(newWrapper, newContent);
                    if (oldWrapper != null)
                    {
                        VisualStateManager.GoToState(newWrapper, "BeforeLoaded", false);
                        VisualStateManager.GoToState(newWrapper, "AfterLoaded", true);
                    }
                }
                this.currentWrappedControl = newWrapper;
            //}
        }
```

Everything works well if i press buttons slowly. But if i press button restlessly it crashes and i get this error :-

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Value does not fall within the expected range.   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property, DependencyObject doh)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase doh, DependencyProperty property, Object obj)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetObjectValueToCore(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.set_Content(Object value)
   at SilverlightTransitionEffect.TransitionalControl.setContent(ContentControl control, Object Content)
   at SilverlightTransitionEffect.TransitionalControl.Update(Object newContent)
   at SilverlightTransitionEffect.TransitionalControl.OnContentChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(DependencyProperty dp, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RefreshExpression(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedWeakListener.SourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject c, DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(DependencyProperty dp, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at SilverlightTransitionEffect.Slideshow.set_SelectedItem(Object value)
   at SilverlightTransitionEffect.Slideshow.btnRightButton_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

I even tried locking object but still the same problem.

This is my visual state :-

```
 <Style x:Key="SlideTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Grid x:Name="grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="LayoutStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5">
                                        <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                            <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                        </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="BeforeLoaded">
                                    <Storyboard >
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="500" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="AfterLoaded"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="BeforeUnloaded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-1000" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform/>
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Ohh! and ya i forgot to tell that the animation runs when i click buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue to this when adding a custom UserControl to a Grid.

I am no expert with naming scopes in Silverlight but I think that may be your problem. In your control template you have the root grid with a name (`x:Name="grid"`) specified. When you start dynamically adding ContentControls using this template to `grid` via the line `grid.Children.Add(newWrapper);` the names are no longer unique (i.e. you have multiple controls named grid, because each newWrapper is templated with a root control using that name). Try giving the dynamically created ContentControl a unique value for Name (unique in the context of the Grids children) before adding it to the Grid.Children collection i.e.

```
ContentControl newWrapper = new ContentControl();

newWrapper.Name = "someUniqueName"; //ensure this is uniquely generated on each call

newWrapper.Style = TransitionStyle;
newWrapper.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
newWrapper.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
grid.Children.Add(newWrapper);
```

Again, because I am no expert on naming scopes I'm not sure what effect this will have on your VSM states where the StoryBoards target the control named grid. At least you will know if this is the problem though.